# Category Menu Navigation in top.links

Tags: menu, navigation, toplinks, submenu

I have searched high and low for an answer on this but have not been able to come up with the solution I am looking for.  I am hoping maybe someone here can point me in the right direction.

I have a website that uses a 2column-left nav layout with no top menu.  I do however have a set of top.links "My Account" "My Wishlist" "My Cart" etc.  It is here I would like to add an additional category menu navigation where a user hovers over something like "Categories" and it drops down through the different levels.

In the file topmenu.phtml I can this by the following code:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Home') ?>    </a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Products') ?></a>
        <?php if($_menu): ?>
            <ul>
                <?php echo $_menu ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
        </li>
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('menu')->toHtml(); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, I cant seem to get this to work in the top.links section "links.phtml", it looks like $_menu is not getting populated.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: links.phtml is responsible for links like My Account, Login/Logout. Topmenu is responsible for showing up categories in horizontal menu - which you have to turn on in configuration. Check your theme for echo: ```<?php echo $this->getHtml('topMenu') ?>```

From what you have wrote:         ```<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('menu')->toHtml(); ?>``` it would check for STATIC BLOCK named with code 'menu'.

Comment: Hi, yes I understand that part.  This is a customization I am looking to make to the theme.  My theme doesnt use a horizontal menu so I am trying to add the categories menu item to the top.links area.  Is there an extension or a simple way to do this?

Comment: Has anyone done this before?